# Loading PHPExcel library in Zend Framework 2 only in current action

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, phpexcel

I would like to use PHPExcel library in a zend framework 2 project. But I don't want to load it for the overall project, just in one particular action. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PHPExcel library is load by `composer.phar` yo can access the class through:

```
$objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();
```

else, you must include path of your library before use :

```
/** Include path **/
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path').';<relative directory path>/');

/** PHPExcel */
include 'PHPExcel.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
```

Answer (score 0):

To use [PHPOffice/PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) library into zend framework 2, you can use the zf2 module [MvlabsPHPExcel](https://github.com/mvlabs/MvlabsPHPExcel).
Through composer:

```
$ php composer.phar require mvlabs/mvlabs-phpexcel
```

And after that you'll be able to use inside you controller particular action:

```
$phpExcelObject = $this->serviceLocator->get('mvlabs.phpexcel.service')->createPHPExcelObject();
```

I recommend to use dependency injection in your controller by injecting the 'mvlabs.phpexcel.service' as a controller dependency.